# Kmeans on “symmetric” data

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, optimization, algorithms, discrete-data

A set is said to be fully-symmetric if for every x in it, negating one of its components results in y such that y is in the set as well.

A set is said to be semi-symmetric if for every x in it, negating all of its components (at once) results in y such that y is in the set as well.

Now examine the optimal solution of the Kmeans objective with K=2d+1 for d-dimensional unique observations that are fully-symmetric.

Suppose it is known that the optimal means set w.r.t the above setup is unique and contains the zero vector. Prove or give a counter example to the following claim: The set of optimal means is semi-symmetric

Comment: Just to check something I must be misunderstanding, let's look at a case with $d=1$.  Let the data be $(-1, -1, -1, -\alpha, 0, \alpha, 2, 2, 2)$ where $\alpha\approx 0$ is very small. Evidently K-means for $2d+1=3$ clusters will return three clusters with cluster means of $-1$, $0$, and $2$. This set of means includes the zero vector. Obviously neither the set of data nor the set of means is semi-symmetric. Why is this not a counterexample? And why do you introduce the concept of "fully symmetric" when the claim appears to have nothing to do with that?

Comment: @whuber - it is known that the observations are fully symmetrical. your example does not satisfy that. I reordered the question a bit, does that help?

Comment: @whuber - one more thing, the observation set must be unique, otherwise the claim can be shown to be false.

Comment: Yes, it helps a lot, thank you. One more thing: it occurs to me that "K-means" refers not to a unique algorithm, but to a class of algorithms, and also that a K-means solution need not be unique in general (which is a hint concerning a possible counterexample: consider the 5-means solutions to the 10-element dataset in $\mathbb{R}^2$ generated by $\{(1,0),(1,7),(1,9)\}$). Do you have a particular algorithm in mind?  The answer could depend on that.

Comment: @whuber - thanks for pointing that out. I added 2 clarifications: the solution is optimal w.r.t to the kmeans objective so it's not algorithm dependent, and it is unique

Comment: If the observation set must be fully symmetric, then it implies $K$ must scale like $2^d$ since for each vector we must be able to swap each of its signs and $2^d+1$ if the observation set includes zero. Correct?

Comment: @Gary - the observation set must indeed scale like you say, but note that $K=2d+1$ and this is enough to satisfy the semi-symmetric condition. Pick any set of $d$ vectors, add their negations, add zero vector and you have a semi-symmetric set of means (yet it is probably not optimal)

Comment: Why was this question downvoted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Under weaker conditions, the assumptions imply the set of optimal means is fully symmetric.**  The proof is trivial, but exposing that triviality (or, perhaps, exposing my misunderstanding of the question!) seems to require a bit of (standard) notation, so let's begin there.

Let me just say at the outset, though, that the intuition is this: if the "set of optimal means" is not *fully* symmetric, then applying an appropriate symmetry to the original set will produce a different set of optimal means that nevertheless achieves the same global minimum value of the K-means objective function, thereby contradicting the hypothesis that the set of optimal means is unique.  Rather than adopt this proof by contradiction, however, I will develop a direct proof involving the same ideas.

Let $X \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be fully symmetric--that is, invariant under the group $G$ generated by the $d$ reflections around the coordinate planes.  Write $x^g$ for the action of $g \in G$ on $x \in X$ and let $Y^g$ = $\{y^g|y \in Y\}$ whenever $Y\subset X$.  A "semi-symmetric" set is invariant under a particular subgroup $H \subset G$; namely, the one generated by the product of those $d$ reflections (in any order--they all commute).  Note that all reflections (and therefore all products of reflections) are Euclidean isometries: they preserve distances.

**K-means clustering** is a distance-based method to partition $X$ into $K$ nonempty subsets $X_1, \ldots, X_K$, thereby determining $K$ corresponding barycenters.  This clustering method does not necessarily yield a unique solution, but we are allowed in this case to assume that *all* K-means solutions determine the same set of barycenters ("the optimal means set is unique").

Because $G$ acts isometrically as a group of permutations on $X$ and the K-means algorithm can be written strictly in terms of distances between elements of $X$, it is immediate that whenever $\{X_1, \ldots, X_K\}$ is a K-means solution then so is $\{X_1^g, \ldots, X_K^g\}$ for any $g\in G$.  The uniqueness assumption tells us that the set of barycenters of the $X_i^g, i=1,\ldots, K,$ equals the set of barycenters of the $X_i, i=1,\ldots, K$.  But, because $g$ is an isometry of $\mathbb{R}^d$ and barycenters are uniquely determined by distance-based criteria, the barycenter of $X_i^g$ is the image under $g$ of the barycenter of $X_i$.  Consequently, the set of barycenters is $G$-invariant (and *a fortiori* it is $H$-invariant), *QED*.

---

It was not necessary either to assume $K=2d+1$ nor to assume $0$ is among the barycenters: uniqueness of the set of barycenters alone implies the conclusion.

**A more interesting conjecture is this:** when $X$ is $G$-invariant, then *there exists* a K-means clustering that is "semisymmetric" (but not all K-means solutions have to enjoy any of the symmetries of $G$).  For example, the center, midpoints, and vertices of a square in $\mathbb{R}^2$, $\{(0,0),(1,0),(0,1),(-1,0),(0,-1),(1,1),(-1,1),(-1,-1),(1,-1)\}$ has some semi-symmetric $5$-means solutions (the origin together with four (vertex, midpoint) pairs) but no fully-symmetric solutions; indeed, it even has some solutions with no symmetry at all.  However, even this conjecture is not generally true.  (Consider the 2-means solutions in $\mathbb{R}^1$ for $X=\{-1,0,1\}$.)  Possibly restricting $K=2d+1$ will make this work, as suggested by the question, but I'm not sure precisely what set of assumptions would be both interesting and lead to a correct conclusion along these lines.

Comment: thanks for a great answer. I have to admit I added "the optimal means set is unique" assumption to remove some of the difficulty but I did not realize this would make things somewhat trivial as you say. I have accepted your answer nonetheless. It would be great to hear your thoughts about this question without the uniqueness assumption - that is, show that every optimal solution is semi-symmetric.

Comment: Leo, it is not the case that every optimal solution is semi-symmetric. Through a random search I was able to find many asymmetric optimal 7-means solutions for the $27$ points located at vertices, edge midpoints, face centers, and center of a cube centered at the origin in $\mathbb{R}^3$, for instance. That is why my "more interesting" conjecture asks only about the *existence* of a semi-symmetric solution.

Comment: did these solutions contain the zero vector?

Comment: I think I found some counter examples myself in 2D. thanks for your efforts!

Comment: It doesn't much matter whether you include $0$ or not, as you can check.